# Choose option by clicking in a <ul> placed in Modal - ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am doing an application. It is a table with some field. 
In particular, there are 2 *selection* and 2 *input*. What I want is shows (in a modal window) the list of item in the first *selection*. Then, clicking confirm, the script choose the option. Then, the second *select* automatically fill with the subarray of the first select. [THIS](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hjmt8GurjKbB7wlLQZ9C?p=preview) is a working and basic example of what I am talking about.

Now, I tried to mix it with my table. In fact I had to edit a bit the code..and infact it doesn't work. You can see it [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/oE5KG81ioLr3PyrsxyBb?p=preview)
(sorry for the bad css, before I want to correct Angular script - anyway, display it as big as you can, so you can see the table better).

The problem in the last code, is that if you click on a item in the list, and then press **Confirm**, the first *select* doesn't change. Why?

I think that the problem is in the last part of the script:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items, $http) {

  $scope.items = items;
$scope.selected = {
item: $scope.items[0]
};


$scope.ok = function () {
 $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
}; 


$scope.cancel = function () {
$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
};
```

I tried to edit it, but I can't find the solution. Can you help me?

P.S. why when the modal is open, the **CSS** of the window behind change?

Thank you in advice!!

Comment: what do you expect from the select box below the button when you click confirm?

Comment: that acts like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Hjmt8GurjKbB7wlLQZ9C?p=preview   if you the link, you see -- select product --. The, if you select an item in the modal window and press confirm, you will show that selected element in the select box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** copy button (that yellow thing) also fixed

### http://plnkr.co/edit/PrT7GAY3ThOUBh5Lxx4i?p=preview

---

http://plnkr.co/edit/JKdfkUNY3cXzEoaN4Lf9?p=preview

Added row as a parameter to `open()`, you should store the row specific data inside the row object

```
  $scope.open = function(row) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modal.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function() {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedProduct) {
      row.selectedProduct = selectedProduct;
    }, function() {
      $log.info('Modal window closed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
```

Comment: It miss one thing to be PERFECT: the copy button doesn't copy the selected item... why? But if I write a number in the <input>, and then i click copy, it is correctly copied

Comment: Unfortunately it works just in part. If I choose a product and click Copy, it adds a new line with already the selected lot  (and this is good), but I still see in the first select with the default option --product-- . It seems it can copy the object well , but she can not do it graphically

Comment: change the implementation, use `row` to store each row data. for example: instead of `$scope.selected...` use `row.selected...`

Comment: It shows me undefined error if I try to write "row" instead of "$scope"

Comment: You need to pass the row as a function param, see the example in my answer

Comment: I tried but I can't solve the problem. Im going to find some jquery solution to copy the text..

Comment: You don't need jquery for that, can you post a fiddle / plunker with your recent attempt?

Comment: No I deleted the updated files, because it very bad. Maybe because I've not understand yet what to exactly do.. the problem is that I am very new in Angular